# Comment s'utiliser les doubles pronoms ? COI et COS

Tags: pronoms, compléments

> Ma sœur Géraldine adore le chocolat. Je **lui en** offre régulièrement.

Pourquoi on dit **lui en** et non **lui le** ou **le lui** ?

> Ma sœur Géraldine adore le chocolat. J'offre chocolat à ma sœur régulièrement.

J'offre **quoi** ? Chocolat = C.O.D.

> Ma sœur Géraldine adore le chocolat. Je **le** offre à ma sœur régulièrement.

J'offre chocolat **à qui** ? À ma sœur = C.O.S.

> Ma sœur Géraldine adore le chocolat. Je **lui** **le** offre régulièrement.

ou

> Ma sœur Géraldine adore le chocolat. Je **le** **lui** offre régulièrement.

Source: Réussir le TCF

Answer (score 3):

La présence du pronom *en* (dans son usage de base), est *toujours* associé a une construction avec *de*. Observons la différence:

> Je lui offre **du** chocolat régulièrement. Je lui **en** offre régulièrement.
>
> Je lui prête **mon** ordinateur régulièrement. Je **le** lui prête régulièrement.
>
> La banque accorde un prêt à ma soeur. Elle **le** lui accorde.

Que ce soit un *de* préposition (Je reviens de chez ma soeur → J'**en** reviens) ou le *de* des article partitif, comme dans ton example, ne change rien. Si le groupe remplacé par le pronom est précédé d'un *de*, c'est *en* qui doit être utilisé.

Le problème est que ton analyse s'arrête au seul nom, alors que c'est *tout le groupe* qui est pertinent dans ce cas de figure! Ce n'est pas "Quoi = chocolat = C.O.D." (soit dit en passant, les grammaire modernes disent seulement "complément direct/indirect", de nos jours), mais bien "Quoi = **du** chocolat = C.O.D.".

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que c'est tout simple ; « le » dans « le chocolat » s'il ne s'agit pas d'une quantité de chocolat déterminée à laquelle on réfère par cet article qui est alors appelé « déterminatif », il ne reste que l'article « le » dans le sens générique ; il ne s'agit ni de l'un ni de l'autre : ce n'est pas une quantité déterminée que l'on aurait mentionnée dans le contexte et  on n'offre pas un concept. Lorsque l'on offre quelque chose soit c'est une chose énumérable et alors on utilise un article indéfini ou un adjectif numéral.

- Elle lui a offert **quatre** cravates à Noël.
- Son fils lui a offert **une** bague pour la fête des mères.

Comme on peut aussi offrir des choses qui ne sont pas énumérables mais qui constituent des masses, la pratique courante est d'utiliser pour celles-ci l'article partitif (de). Puisque le chocolat est une de ces chose qui ne s'énumère pas on dit « offrir du chocolat » (« de le chocolat », se rappeler de la contraction de « de le » en « du »), ce qui signifie que l'on offre une certaine quantité de chocolat.

Le pronom qui est utilisé pour remplacer l'article partitif est « en » ; ceci est affirmé dans la remarque « 4 » sous l'entrée de « en² », pronom neutre.

> 4. À l'intérieur de la prop. où il est placé, « en » remplit auprès des termes de cette prop. **toutes les fonctions** assumées par « **de** », soit dans ses emplois de prép., soit dans ses emplois d'**art**. indéf. ou **partitif**.

Comme le verbe « offrir » et le mot « chocolat » forcent un partitif, pour remplacer une certaine quantité de chocolat, un pronom qui couvre cette fonction partitive est nécessaire, et ce pronom ne peut être que « en ».

« De le chocolat » ou correctement dit selon le principe de contraction, « du chocolat », est remplacé par « en ». Il n'y a pas d'autre pronom qui couvre cette fonction partitive.

Même s'il s'agissait d'un chocolat particulier, comme par exemple du chocolat blanc aux noisettes, cela constitue encore une masse et il faudrait dire « Je lui **en** offre régulièrement. ».

---

- Ma soeur Géraldine adore le chocolat. J'offre chocolat à ma soeur régulièrement.

Cela ne se dit pas ; en français il faut un article partitif avant « chocolat ».

> - Ma soeur Géraldine adore le chocolat. J'offre **du** chocolat à ma sœur. régulièrement.

Les trois dernières phrases ne conviennent pas ; il est nécessaire d'utiliser une forme qui confère l'idée de partitif et il n'y a que « en » qui convienne ; « le » n'est pas le bon pronom.

Answer (score 0):

Ma sœur aime mon ordinateur (le mien, pas les ordinateurs en général). Je le (mon ordinateur, masculin) lui (ma sœur) prête souvent.

Ma sœur aime ma radio (ou ma brosse à dents, mais la mienne en particulier). Je la (ma radio, féminin) lui (ma sœur) prête souvent.

Ma sœur aime le chocolat (en général, pas la tablette dans ma poche). Je lui (ma sœur) en (du chocolat) offre souvent.

L'usage a défini des tournures de phrases qui s'acquièrent en lisant beaucoup, plutôt qu'en apprenant des règles de grammaire.

La grammaire est utile pour commencer l'apprentissage de la langue. Ensuite, il faut écouter la musicalité des phrases -- du moins, c'est la méthode que j'utilise et que je préconise (sourire).